# Are paid salon listings worthwihile?

Tags: seo, directory-listing

Are paid salon listings worthwhile (for seo)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. Links from most directories carry extremely little SEO value due to the fact that those pages themselves have little SEO value so a link from them won't do too much for a website. However, if you're targeting a specific geographic region, these *may* be helpful if the directory offers categories for that specific geographic region and the page containing the link isn't full of links to your competitors.

Comment: Also, "Buying or selling links that pass PageRank is in violation of Google's Webmaster Guidelines and can negatively impact a site's ranking in search results." http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66736